# How do I train my DNNClassifier model (in tensorflow), to learn from new training cases? I do not have access to the initial CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

How do I train my DNNClassifier model (in tensorflow), to learn from new training cases? I do not have access to the initial CSV file.

Suppose I have used

```
  classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                      hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                      n_classes=3,
                                      model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
```

Now before I use it for testing, I want to train it on more data. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run something like:

```
classifier.train(input_fn=my_training_set, steps=1000)
```

This should continue training the model based on what is in '/tmp/iris_model' (you might have to play with the `steps` parameter).

The end-result might not be better than what you have when you start. Since you don't have the original data, the data you are adding might have a different distribution. As the model trains it might forget the original data and perform worse overall. You will need to experiment.